# Angular 2 Album create

Tags: javascript, angular

I want to make an Album creator like on Facebook.

But when I save a picture to the firebase storage and I get back the URL to the picture I put in an object, but the view is not refreshing just if I add a new picture or move the cursor. How can I refresh the view automatically when I get the URL from firebase?

```
    <div class="row pics">
        <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-4">
            <div class="newItem text-center">
                <a (change)="addPicture($event)" class="newAlbum"><input type="file" id="file"/>Add Picture</a>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-4" *ngFor="let item of newAlbum.pictures; let i = index">
            <div class="Item">
                <img src="{{item?.pictureS}}" alt="" >
            </div>
            <textarea class="picture-desc" placeholder="Say something about this photo..." (keyup)="onKey($event,i)">{{item.desc}}</textarea>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Backend

```
 readPicture() {
   this.picItem = { pictureS: '', pictureF: this.file, desc: '' };
   let that = this;
   let uploadTask = this.data.albumUpload(this.newAlbum.dirname,this.file.name,this.file);

   uploadTask.on('state_changed', function(snapshot) {
      var progress = (snapshot.bytesTransferred / snapshot.totalBytes) * 100;
      console.log('Upload is ' + progress + '% done');
    }, function(error) {  
    }, function() {
        that.picItem.pictureS = uploadTask.snapshot.downloadURL;
        console.log(' NEW UPLOAD...');
        that.newAlbum.pictures.push(that.picItem);
       }
    );
 }

 addPicture(e){
   this.file = e.target.files[0];
   this.readPicture();    
 }

 onKey(e,i){
   this.newAlbum.pictures[i].desc = e.target.value;
 }

 albumUpload(form: NgForm){
   this.newAlbum.title = form.value.album_title;
   this.newAlbum.desc = form.value.album_desc;
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `NgZone` to to trigger change detection when certain actions are done. You need to inject `NgZone` into the component. Once thats done you can use , `run` to update DOM.

```
  constructor( public zone: NgZone){}
  that.zone.run(() =>
    that.newAlbum.pictures.push(that.picItem);
  });
```

You can read more about `ngZone` [here](https://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/02/01/zones-in-angular-2.html) .

**ps**: I would advice you to use new `arrow funcions` to conserve `this` rather than using `that`.